# how to pass a value from one javascript file into another javascript file

Tags: javascript, ajax

Currently, by using the "$.getScript" jquery method I am able to pass the pass parameters from one javascript file into another javascript file. For instance, this $.getScript call made on javascript file name "secondJavaScript.js" file to call the function name callMemoPage() from "firstJavaScript.js" file. I am passing the following "pageName", "acctNum" paramaters from "secondJavaScript.js" into "firstJavaScript.js" file. However, the issue how to get the value of the function "callMemoPage" into this "secondJavascript.js" file. And that value kept in variable "Memo" - which is in "firstJavaScript.js" file.

```
$.getScript('firstJavaScript.js', function(){
  
  getMemo();
  
  function getMemo(){
    
    var pageName = "Memo Page"
    var acctNum = "123"
    
    // callMemoPage function located in "firstJavaScript.js" file
    callMemoPage(pageName, acctNum)
    console.log(Memo);
    
  }
  
});

// firstJavaSctipt.js file

function callMemoPage(pageName, acctNum){
  
  var Memo;
  
  if(pageName == 'Memo Page') && (acctNum = '123'){
    function(memoField){
       var memoField = window.open("https://www.example.com");
      // question how to pass the value of Memo into secondJavaScript.js file 
      Memo = $(memoField).find('input[name="MEMO"]').val();
    }
   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it to a **JSON** file using the **fs** module :

```js
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('file.json', JSON.stringify(yourVariable));

// Other file
const myVariable = require('file.json');
```

Answer (score 0):

If these two pages are in the same origin: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy, you can store the result of `Memo` in a cookie and then access it in the second page

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have multiple functions in fileOne.js, and you want to use them in fileTwo.js.
well in HTML you import them like this:

```
<html>
 ...
 <script src="fileOne.js">
 <script src="fileTwo.js">
 ...
</html>
```

Notice that **fileOne.j**s must be before **fileTwo.js**, so every variable in fileOne.js will be available in fileTwo.js.
That's because HTML is **synchronous**.